# imap_search return blank result

Tags: php, email, imap

I have a gmail account; Three other emails are related to this one.

When I receive an email at **xxx@mydomain.com** it will be transferred to **xxx@gmail.com**.

Also when I send a message I can use an alias which mean that using gmail I send a mail with my xxx@mydomain.com.

When I use imap_search, From **xxx@mydomain.com** or To **xxx@mydomain.com** the result is blank but messages exist in my Inbox. Is this a problem of imap_search?

Comment: the from\to headers are probably being changed by what ever method you are using to redirect the email

Comment: For example: I try to extract mail FROM xxx@mydomain.com which exist in my gmail.com but no result is returned. I hope I did understand well your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution is:**

The default folder when we make imap_connection is INBOX. When we try to make imap_sort or iamp_search. We don't get anyresult. We have to switch to the folder which contain all messages for example **[GMAIl]/All**.